# Why does the following function to compare vectors not work?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have created a function template to compare two inputs. In one case I wanted to make an overload to it to compare two vectors. But it doesn't work. It somehow compares the location of the two vectors.

Please go through the code and debug the issue.

```
//Learning

#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> T larger( T first, T second);
int main() {

    std::vector<int>bc{ 1,5,2,3,4,5,6 };
    std::vector<int>ab{ 1,2,3,4,5,8,10 };
    
    std::vector<int> res{ *larger(&ab,&bc) };
    for (int i : res) {
        std::cout << i << "\t";
    }
}


//Largerfunction begins

template <typename T>
T larger(T first, T second) {
    if (first > second) {               //General definition for any static data type for Larger function
        return first;
    }
    else {
        return second;
    }

}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>* larger(std::vector<T>*first, std::vector<T>*second) {       //Overload on the Larger function for pas by pointer for std::vector data type
    size_t i{};
    while ((*first)[i] != (*first)[-1] or (*second)[i] != (*second)[-1]) {
        if ((*first)[i] > (*second)[i]) {
            return first;
        }
        else if ((*first)[i] < (*second)[i]) {
            return second;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if ((*first)[i] == (*first)[-1]) {
        return second;
    }
    else{
        return first;
    }

}
```

Comment: You did not declare the second overload before you use it in `main`. Also, why does this overload take the vector by-pointer? According to the first overload the argument is expected to be given by-value. But most like by-reference would be the best approach.

Comment: Also, the second overload is not needed at all. Vectors can be compared with `<` and so on. The comparison will be lexicographic.

Comment: `while ((*first)[i] != (*first)[-1] or (*second)[i] != (*second)[-1])` doesn't work. First, you are comparing the _values_ at the indices, not whether the _indices_ coincide. Second, you can't get the end of a container with `[-1]` in C++. It will just cause undefined behavior. You can use `.begin()` to get an iterator to the first element and `.end()` to get an iterator one-past the container, which you can then iterate and compare. Or if you stay with indices compare `i` against `.size()`.

Comment: And of course all of this can be simply replaced by `auto res = std::max(ab, bc);`.

Comment: There are a lot of things in your code that prompt me to think you come from python or a similar language. There are significant differences, for example when it comes to array indexing, between C++ and python. For example `x[-1]` does not do what you likely think it does. Have a look through https://cppreference.com and check how the types you use work.

Comment: @bitmask Yeah, I did Python first. Now I am learning C++.

Comment: @user17732522 I was trying to do it to get the logic hence i didn't use the `std::max()` here.

Comment: I finally made it work.
https://github.com/ragnar-vallhala/cppfiles/blob/main/comparingvectors.cpp